# python-openstackclient issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python, openstack

Installed versions:

python-openstackclient==3.17.0

osc-lib==1.11.1

All openstack commands seem to work except the following:

`openstack stack show <stack name or id>`

The response i get is: `issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`

I have read that this might be osc-lib problem, but in version 1.11.1 it should be fixed. How can i get this to work?

Comment: I did not fix this exact issue. As expected the problem was with python dependencies, so i just installed new pyenv and then my openstackclient was working properly

Answer (score 0):

> This problem only occurs when you are using Python 3.7

By using Python 3.6 this problem does not exist anymore. There is a link below describes this problem any probable patch to solve this problem.

Here is the link on OpenStack forum that describes the same issue:
https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/118057/solved-in-py37-rocky-openstackclient-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class/

Comment: you wirk still with Python

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi The word do that, First choice for the back-end